# Flask-pymongo RuntimeError: Working outside of application context

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, flask-pymongo

I'm writing a program to read mongodb document based on id field using flask-pymongo. But I'm getting error, can anybody tell me where am I going wrong?

code:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, jsonify
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from collections import OrderedDict
from bson import json_util
import json

app = Flask('__name__')
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'db_name'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://192.168.55.24:27017/db_name'
mongo_connection = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/')
def index(inp_id):
    collection = mongo_connection.db.table_name
    one_record = collection.find_one({'id': inp_id})
    obj_str = json_util.dumps(one_record)
    obj_dict = json.loads(obj_str, object_hook=OrderedDict)
    return make_response(jsonify(obj_dict), 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    index('5cd00a468b36db516b6d2f16')   # I think this is where I'm going wrong
```

giving me the below error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

If I pass id value directly in the place of inp_id I get the result but I'm trying to write a generic one.

Answer (score 0):

Flask has an application context, You might need to use `app.app_context()` to make it work.

> The application context keeps track of the application-level data
>   during a request, CLI command, or other activity. Rather than passing
>   the application around to each function, the **current_app** and **g** proxies
>   are accessed instead.

Try this :

```
def index(inp_id):
    with app.app_context():
        collection = mongo_connection.db.table_name
        one_record = collection.find_one({'id': inp_id})
        obj_str = json_util.dumps(one_record)
        obj_dict = json.loads(obj_str, object_hook=OrderedDict)
        return make_response(jsonify(obj_dict), 200)
```

For more information, read [Flask Application context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context)

Comment: That is giving me TypeError: index() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: did you call index with arguments?

Comment: can you try passing the argument to app context like :  `app_context(inp_id)` and see if it works

Comment: I solved it by passing 'inp_id' parameter to @app.route. Thanks for your time